# fast conversion of a text file to arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, large-data

I've been working on a project that involves large heightmaps (3000x3000 ~60MB). . What i need to do is to split the data into several 200x200 arrays (15x15 of them), then save them separately (but this time in a format which is as fast as possible to load again). I've tried using streams (I'm not that good at C++ so don't exclude ideas with streams) but it's agonizingly slow.

Stuff that might help (based on what I've seen while searching for the answer):
The heightmaps are supplied as text files (.asc) with the numbers written like this "125.123" but without the "". Each entry has three decimals no matter what the number is ("0.123" and "100.123").As far as i know there are no negative numbers and the size of the heightmap is known beforehand (usually 3000x3000).

So my questions essentially:

1. Whats the best way to do this? (preferably without boost or such but if it helps a lot then why not)
2. What format (for the 200x200 arrays) would allow the fastest loading time?

any help, ideas, code or links/litterature?

Comment: This is much easier to do in Python. Why C++ specifically?

Comment: Usually the bottleneck is the disk.  The best format for loading is usually the smallest.    How fast are they loading?

Comment: Did you mean "000.123" instead of "0.123" ? If not, I dont understand what you mean with 3 decimals

Comment: @Bharadwaj, the rest of the program is in C++ so it would make sense to use it. It's not absolutely necessary however. What makes python so much easier?

Comment: @tobi, i meant "0.123" and what i mean with decimals is the that there is alway three digits after the dot.

Comment: Not just Python, but any scripting language, Python because parsing is much easier and faster, has a great string library, data conversions is very easy. just try it

Comment: Alright i will, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

part 2

If you are reading the file back onto the same type of system (endianness) then use a binary blittable format. Ie store a straight binary dump of the 200 * 200 array. I would also multiply by 1000 and store as ints since they are typically slightly faster (you did not mention the range of values, nor the required precision, are the units feet, miles, nanometers?)

Comment: Its a real world heightmap with ranges typically between 0-500. Thanks for the tip i will look into that!